# WooCommerce custom shortcode product categories dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, shortcode

I am trying to add a WooCommerce categories-dropdown-shortcode, but this seems to not work. I am able to see the drop down, but when i choose a category it doesn't register and nothing happens.

sc:  **[product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0" hierarchical="0"]**

Code that's placed in my functions.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Extra Feature
 * --------------------------
 *
 * Register a shortcode that creates a product categories dropdown list
 *
 * Use: [product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0"                hierarchical="0"]
 *
 */
add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown','woo_product_categories_dropdown' );
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'count'         => '0',
    'hierarchical'  => '0',
    'orderby'       => ''
    ), $atts));

     ob_start();

    $c = $count;
$h = $hierarchical;
$o = ( isset( $orderby ) && $orderby != '' ) ? $orderby : 'order';

// Stuck with this until a fix for      http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories( $c, $h, 0, $o );
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var product_cat_dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown_product_cat");
    function onProductCatChange() {
        if ( product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value !=='' ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat="+product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    product_cat_dropdown.onchange = onProductCatChange;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php

return ob_get_clean();

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update *(2019)*

Here below is the working code version for this custom product category dropdown shortcode since woocommerce 3 release:

- `wc_product_dropdown_categories()` replace `woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories()` which was deprecated since woocommerce 3
- Modified Javascript/jQuery code.
- Some other light changes.

The new working code:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown', 'shortcode_product_categories_dropdown' );
function shortcode_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'show_count'    => '0',
        'hierarchical'  => '0',
        'orderby'       => ''
    ), $atts, 'product_categories_dropdown' );

    ob_start();

    wc_product_dropdown_categories( array(
        'show_count'    => $atts['show_count'],
        'hierarchical'  => $atts['hierarchical'],
        'orderby'       => ( isset($atts['orderby'])  && empty($atts['orderby']) ? $atts['orderby'] : 'order' ),
    ) );
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.dropdown_product_cat').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() !=='' ) {
                location.href = '<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat='+$(this).val();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE example:**

1) Inside a Page or post content text Editor *(or a text widget)*:

```
[product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0" hierarchical="0"]
```

2) On a php template or code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[product_categories_dropdown orderby='title' count='0' hierarchical='0']");
```

---

**Original answer:**

If you read the comments for the source of this code that you have picked [**here**](https://gist.github.com/corsonr/6681929), they were some errors and they found some turn around recently.

So the correct updated code seems to be this one:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce Extra Feature Shortcode
 * --------------------------
 *
 * Register a shortcode that creates a product categories dropdown list
 *
 * Use: [product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0" hierarchical="0"]
 *
 */
add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown', 'woo_product_categories_dropdown' );
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'show_count'    => '0',
        'hierarchical'  => '0',
        'orderby'       => ''
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();

    $c = $count;
    $h = $hierarchical;
    $o = ( isset( $orderby ) && $orderby != '' ) ? $orderby : 'order';

    // Stuck with this until a fix for http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
    woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories( $c, $h, 0, $o );
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        var product_cat_dropdown = jQuery(".dropdown_product_cat");
        function onProductCatChange() {
            if ( product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value !=='' ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat="+product_cat_dropdown.options[product_cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        }
        product_cat_dropdown.onchange = onProductCatChange;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

> **But it will not work**, as **`woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories()`** is a buggy function that is deprecated. See [**this reference**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories.html) about.

May be you could try to use [**this plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/) instead, for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still stuck on this then here is the currently working solution:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce Extra Feature Shortcode
 * --------------------------
 *
 * Register a shortcode that creates a product categories dropdown list
 *
 * Use: [product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0" hierarchical="0"]
 *
 */
add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown', 'woo_product_categories_dropdown' );
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'show_count'    => '0',
        'hierarchical'  => '0',
        'orderby'       => ''
    ), $atts));

    ob_start();

    $c = $count;
    $h = $hierarchical;
    $o = ( isset( $orderby ) && $orderby != '' ) ? $orderby : 'order';

    // Stuck with this until a fix for http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
    wc_product_dropdown_categories( $c, $h, 0, $o );
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        var product_cat_dropdown = jQuery(".dropdown_product_cat");
        product_cat_dropdown.change(function() {
            if ( product_cat_dropdown.val() !=='' ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat="+product_cat_dropdown.val();
            }
        });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: any idea how i modify this to show the children of one category rather than a list of all categories?