# Display subcategory dropdown on Woocommerce subcategory pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2, taxonomy-terms

I am using *[Display sub subcategories terms list on WooCommerce subcategory archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264851/display-sub-subcategories-terms-list-on-woocommerce-subcategory-archive-pages/63272238#63272238)* answer code to my previous question, to display my subcategories on parent category pages in my Woocommerce shop

Now I would like it to be displayed as a dropdown *(ideally a **select2 dropdown like** the other WooCommerce dropdowns)* rather than plain links.

I know that I could use `wc_product_dropdown_categories()`, but how can I display the sub subcategories on the main parent subcategory pages as a dropdown?

Comment: What do you mean by "dropdown"? Do you mean a dropdown-menu or a `<select>` form input?

Comment: A select dropdown, ideally a select2 dropdown like the other Woocommerce dropdowns like country-select.

Comment: Well then I suggest you start by reading the documentation of select2: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage It's really straight forward

Comment: Also, a `<select>` input is meant to be a form input, not as navigation. If I get your question right, you basically want an `<a>` tag in an `<option>` tag. Which is not going to work.

You can use CSS to style your `<ul class="subcategories-list">` tag as a dropdown menu. That will be a much better approach

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yes you can, but nothing in the OP's question points to the fact he's using JS or an XMLHttpRequest. I'm talking HTML here... a `<select>` outside a `<form>` makes no sense semantically

Comment: @jrswgtr Can you help me how to style the ul into a dropdown?

Comment: @Arkansas44 have a look at this article: https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

Comment: @jrswgtr I need the dropdown to be displayed on click though, not on hover. It should look like a product filter.

Comment: @Arkansas44 Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css And with a bit of creativity in CSS you can make it look as you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a custom shortcode will display a **Select2 dropdown** of linked sub subcategories terms list.

> **Note:** The **Select2 library** *(and styles)* **is not loaded by default on WooCommerce Archive pages**. So there are included in this shortcode using external links from a CDN, and loaded only on subcategories.
>
> You can replace that with the files included in WooCommerce, using WordPress enqueuing recommended way, if you like.

The code:

```
add_shortcode('wc_subcat_dropdown', 'wc_sub_subcategories_dropdown');
function wc_sub_subcategories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attribute (or argument)
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'obj_id'   => '0',
    ), $atts, 'wc_subcat_dropdown' ) );

    if ( $obj_id > 0 ) :
        $obj = new WP_Term( (int) $obj_id );
    else :
        $obj = get_queried_object();
    endif;

    if ( is_a($obj, 'WP_Term') && $taxonomy === $obj->taxonomy && 0 != $obj->parent ) :
        // Get sub-subcategories of the current subcategory
        $terms = get_terms([
            'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
            'hide_empty'  => true,
            'parent'      => $obj->term_id
        ]);
    endif;

    if ( isset($terms) && ! empty($terms) ) :

    ob_start(); // Start buffering

    // Select2 CSS - Can be removed and replaced
    echo '<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />';

    echo '<select name="product_cat" id="'.$taxonomy.'" class="dropdown_'.$taxonomy.'">
        <option value="">'.__("Select a subcategory","woocommerce").'</option>';

    // Loop through product subcategories WP_Term Objects
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<option value="'. $term->slug .'">'. $term->name .'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    // Select2 Script - Can be removed and replaced
    echo '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>';
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
        $('select#<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>').select2();
        $('.dropdown_product_cat').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() !=='' ) {
                location.href = '<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?product_cat='+$(this).val();
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### USAGE:

1. In WordPress the text editor, text widget… (as a shortcode)

   ```
   [wc_subcat_dropdown]
   ```
2. Inside php code, like a template file, any hooked function…

   ```
   echo do_shortcode('[wc_subcat_dropdown]');
   ```

   or

   ```
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[wc_subcat_dropdown]'); ?>
   ```

---

#### Example Usage:

Using a hooked function and displaying the dropdown below the subcategory title:

```
add_action( "woocommerce_archive_description", "custom_sub_category_dropdown", 5 );
function custom_sub_category_dropdown(){
    echo do_shortcode('[wc_subcat_dropdown]');
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Optional Shortcode arguments:**

- `$id` - Define a subcategory term Id *(the current subcategory term Id by default)*
- `$taxonomy` - By default, WooCommerce product category taxonomy.

---

Related:

- [Display sub subcategories terms list on WooCommerce subcategory archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264851/display-sub-subcategories-terms-list-on-woocommerce-subcategory-archive-pages/63272238#63272238)
- [WooCommerce custom shortcode product categories dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029043/woocommerce-custom-shortcode-product-categories-dropdown/41029296#41029296)